# Order by in subquery behaving differently than native sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am honestly a little puzzled by this!

I have a query that returns a set of transactions that contain both repair costs and an odometer reading at the time of repair on the master level.  To get an accurate Cost per mile reading I need to do a subquery to get both the first meter reading between a starting date and an end date, and an ending meter.

```
(select top 1 wf2.ro_num
from wotrans wotr2
left join wofile wf2 
  on wotr2.rop_ro_num = wf2.ro_num 
  and wotr2.rop_fac = wf2.ro_fac
where wotr.rop_veh_num = wotr2.rop_veh_num 
and wotr.rop_veh_facility = wotr2.rop_veh_facility
AND ((@sdate = '01/01/1900 00:00:00' and wotr2.rop_tran_date = 0) 
  OR ([dbo].[udf_RTA_ConvertDateInt](@sdate) <= wotr2.rop_tran_date 
  AND [dbo].[udf_RTA_ConvertDateInt](@edate) >= wotr2.rop_tran_date))
order by wotr2.rop_tran_date asc) as highMeter
```

The reason I have the tables aliased as xx2 is because those tables are also used in the main query, and I don't want these to interact with each other except to pull the correct vehicle number and facility.

Basically when I run the main query it returns a value that is not correct; it returns the one that is second(keep in mind that the first and second have the same date.)  But when I take the subquery and just copy and paste it into it's own query and run it, it returns the correct value.

I do have a work around for this, but I am just curious as to why this happening.  I have searched quite a bit and found not much(other than the fact that people don't like order bys in subqueries).  Talking to one of my friends that also does quite a bit of SQL scripting, it looks to us as if the subquery is ordering differently than the subquery by itsself when you have multiple values that are the same for the order by(i.e. 10 dates of 08/05/2016).

Any ideas would be helpful!

Like I said I have a work around that works in this one case, but don't know yet if it will work on a larger dataset.

Let me know if you want more code.

Comment: Im not sure what maybe the problem, and without data sample is even difficult to understand. But looks like you should take a look to `ROW_NUMBER()` that probably will make your life easier.

Comment: This isn't enough for us to help - see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for what's missing. But note that if you `ORDER BY` a column with many identical values, the ordering of rows with the same value should be regarded as *arbitrary*. That is, if there are many rows with the same `rop_tran_date`, you need to tell SQL Server how to choose between them, if you want to be guaranteed of always getting the same one.

Comment: Yeah I knew that it would be hard to understand because this is very specific. I am kind of looking to see if anybody else has had a similar issue.  That is why I tried explaining my best the objective and outcome I am seeing.  Would it help if I shared my resultant dataset in my 2 trials(query as subquery and query by its self)?

Comment: Just fyi I deployed the work around on my larger dataset and it worked just fine.  So this question is purely informational for me now.